# Forcing subclasses of a base class to pass a parameter to the base, Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I want a base class that is passed in a stackview by anything that subclasses it. I have been trying to achieve this through init methods, but keep getting errors. Maybe there is a way using protocols. Currently, my code looks likes this:

```
class newBatchViewController: UIViewController {
    //XXX working  to get all subclasses of newBatchController to have to pass in a stackView
    var entriesStackView : UIStackView
//    convenience init () {
//        self.init(entriesStackView: nil)
//    }
    // Pass in entriesStackView from anything that subclasses
    init(nibName: String? = nil, bundle: Bundle? = nil, entriesStackView: UIStackView?) {
        self.entriesStackView = entriesStackView!
        super.init(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)

    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
//        self.entriesStackView = entriesStackView
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

And in an example subclass:

```
class stepOneViewController: newBatchViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var testStackView: UIStackView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    
    init() {
        super.init(entriesStackView: testStackView)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

The idea is that there are common elements like buttons that I want to set up in the base class withint the passed in stackView and then any subclass will have those buttons and setup within the stackview that it passed to the base class. Any help is appreciated!

Edit: The exact error I am getting right now is

```
Property 'self.entriesStackView' not initialized at super.init call
```

on the super.init(coder: aDecoder) line.

Comment: Maybe you should look into a design pattern like Builder or Factory instead of using inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you posted the errors you are getting so the community can address those individually.

That said, it sounds like you are trying to force new subclasses to always have a UIStackView that gets passed into init and you want to prohibit other versions of init from being called.  You can't really remove the other versions of init() that are already declared as part of UIViewController, but you could override as many of them as you can find and add asserts/exceptions with messaging suggesting to use your custom initializer.

You could also implement a static create() method that takes the parameters you want and have folks use that.

In the functions handling the presentation of the UIViewController you could also add asserts/exceptions if entriesStackView was not set so users of your class know that something went wrong and that entriesStackView needs to be set before the view controller is presented.

You could move the setup of entriesStackView into a setEntriesStackView() function, so that users of your code could delay setting the variable if they wished, but still provide the init function option if they like. Enforcement could still be accomplished by asserts/exceptions in the places where the view controller is presented.

Comment: Lol if I can't figure this out soon I'll just accept the laggy storyboards and copy and paste... But I would say that I'm not trying to remove the other versions of init that are already declared as a part of UIViewController, I just want to add a parameter that needs to get passed in to this subclass of UIVIewController by anything that subclasses this subclass.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the root of my problem, for those also searching, is that the storyboard initializes the viewcontrollers, so custom initializations through the code are not possible if you are using storyboard. There might be a different way to do dependency injection here, but I've lost my patience with the problem. Someone correct me if I'm wrong about this analysis.